# Qt6: how to disable selection for empty cells in QTableView?

Tags: python-3.9, pyside6, qt6

I'm trying to display some data from a database in a grid view, similar to how a file manager works. I thought of using a `QTableView` as the grid view since it did what I wanted out of the box. However, as shown with the below given MRE, even if just a single cell has  value, you can still select the other empty cells, how can I prevent this? Basically, I want to make it so that only cells with a value can be selected.

MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc


ROW_COUNT = 5
COL_COUNT = 5

class Model(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._data = [[None for _ in range(COL_COUNT)] for _ in range(ROW_COUNT)]

    def data(self, index: qtc.QModelIndex, role: qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        
        if role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

        return None

    def setData(self, index: qtc.QModelIndex, value, role: qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole=qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if  not index.isValid():
            return False

        if role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value

        return False

    def rowCount(self, _):
        return ROW_COUNT
    
    def columnCount(self, _):
        return COL_COUNT

app = qtw.QApplication()
view = qtw.QTableView()
view.setModel(Model())
view.setShowGrid(False)
view.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
view.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
view.model().setData(view.model().createIndex(0, 0), "this is a test")
view.show()
app.exec()
```

[image]

Comment: Override [`flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) and ensure that it doesn't return the [`Qt.ItemIsSelectable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) value.

Comment: @musicamante thank you, the empty cells are no longer selectable. Though, clicking on the empty cells does not seem to clear the selection, is there a way I can do that? Kind of like how clicking on any area outside the `QTableView` clears the selection.

Comment: Note: you should use [`index()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index), not `createIndex()` (which is used for internal model implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the [`flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) and ensure that it doesn't return the `ItemIsSelectable` flag.

```
class Model(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if index.data() is None:
            flags &= ~qtc.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        return flags
```

In your case, you also probably want to avoid the `ItemIsEnabled`, and since these two flags are the default one, you can just return `NoItemFlags`

```py
    def flags(self, index):
        if index.data() is None:
            return qtc.Qt.NoItemFlags
        return super().flags(index)
```

If you also need to clear the selection, then you could subclass the view and do it in the `mousePressEvent()`:

```py
class TableView(qtw.QTableView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if index.isValid() and not index.flags() & qtc.Qt.ItemIsSelectable:
            self.clearSelection()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)
```